# This code giving error

Tags: java, json, api, getjson

```
 import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
 import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
 import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
 import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

 public class ActOn {

  static String BASE_URL = "https://restapi.actonsoftware.com/";
  static String ACTON_USERNAME = "";
  static String ACTON_PASSWORD = "";
  static String CLIENT_ID = "";
  static String CLIENT_SECRET = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
   try {
    String access_token = getAccessToken();
    Unirest.setDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
    printListCount();
   } catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  private static void printListCount() throws UnirestException, JSONException {
   HttpResponse < JsonNode > listResponse = Unirest.get(BASE_URL + "/api/1/list").asJson();
   System.out.println("Total number of lists : " + listResponse.getBody().getObject().getInt("totalCount"));
  }
  private static String getAccessToken() throws UnirestException, JSONException {
   HttpResponse < JsonNode > jsonResponse = Unirest.post(BASE_URL + "token")
    .header("accept", "application/json")
    .field("grant_type", "password")
    .field("username", ACTON_USERNAME)
    .field("password", ACTON_PASSWORD)
    .field("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
    .field("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
    .asJson();
   return jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().getString("access_token");

  }
 }
```

This code is giving the error;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.withCharset(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.body.MultipartBody.field(MultipartBody.java:107)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.body.MultipartBody.field(MultipartBody.java:73)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody.field(HttpRequestWithBody.java:95)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody.field(HttpRequestWithBody.java:87)
    at ActOn.getAccessToken(ActOn.java:48)
    at ActOn.main(ActOn.java:20)
```

I can not understand how to solve this problem. I have added all the required jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have incompatible versions of `http-core` and `unirest-java` in your Project.

Comment: I have included "http-core 4.2.3 and unirest-java 1.4.7".

Comment: Hey Jens I have included the jar file. Now error is change to "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet   at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at ActOn.getAccessToken(ActOn.java:56)
    at ActOn.main(ActOn.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: @AbhimanyuJha You http-client Version should also be version 4.3

Comment: I added http-client4.3 but the error is same as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson"

Comment: You added it to your classpath or only to your build path?

Comment: I have added this in build path............. because i have only jar file of http-core, http-mime, unirest-java. http-client, org.json, java.json

Comment: Its giving the above error in this line that "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet" 

   HttpResponse < JsonNode > jsonResponse = Unirest.post(BASE_URL + "token")
    .header("accept", "application/json")
    .field("grant_type", "password")
    .field("username", ACTON_USERNAME)
    .field("password", ACTON_PASSWORD)
    .field("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
    .field("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
    .asJson();